# Ruby on Rails Sign in Issues ( Used Rails admin Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

Recently we are planning to upgrade the Ruby on Rails app **(Ruby 2.7.2 to 3.* , Rails 5.2 to 7.*)** . After upgrading the versions we tested in local it is working as we expecting, then we deployed the project to Heroku staging environment. When we try to login the application it throws an error like below. [image]

We are capturing the log , but couldn't under stand what it is saying.

```
2023-08-01T19:06:41.277239+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/sign_in" host=rbtest-backendv5-staging-0c772eac5283.herokuapp.com request_id=4d638847-cfc9-4480-b8e6-beb943f55d72 fwd="49.206.41.146" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=3113 protocol=https
2023-08-01T19:06:41.623330+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-91fe79ba016355ea4feedb4cd979dbdc1850af06c4d85e050fd713602dfef12b.css" host=rbtest-backendv5-staging-0c772eac5283.herokuapp.com request_id=af0de2be-214c-45f6-8f3c-ec85b6bcdaa0 fwd="49.206.41.146" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=112 protocol=https
2023-08-01T19:06:41.638424+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-817edcc6fa758f17e2e286c67711f3aab5d5b28a0f12e819c3c6c27df9867310.js" host=rbtest-backendv5-staging-0c772eac5283.herokuapp.com request_id=7265b9d1-a53f-4503-88a1-2ec0264d9489 fwd="49.206.41.146" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=112 protocol=https
2023-08-01T19:06:57.796948+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-08-01T19:06:57.796888 #2]  INFO -- : [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 49.206.41.146 at 2023-08-01 19:06:57 +0000
2023-08-01T19:06:57.797808+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-08-01T19:06:57.797768 #2]  INFO -- : [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
2023-08-01T19:06:57.797845+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-08-01T19:06:57.797825 #2]  INFO -- : [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DmqkcI42fLTL1M7Z/fNx3IvIa1RpxBOplMi6r1xpIK8j4Rq3/NduVBmXxYEN7NQXEe9Sy1cEBfAMr6QfFvAHQg==", "user"=>{"email"=>"admin@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
2023-08-01T19:06:57.811504+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2023-08-01T19:06:57.811430 #2] DEBUG -- : [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0]   User Load (3.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "admin@example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2023-08-01T19:06:57.926415+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-08-01T19:06:57.926342 #2]  INFO -- : [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 128ms (ActiveRecord: 3.7ms | Allocations: 1047)
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927623+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2023-08-01T19:06:57.927555 #2] FATAL -- : [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0]
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927624+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927625+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0]
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927625+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] activerecord (6.1.7.4) lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:43:in `save'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927625+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] scout_apm (2.6.10) lib/scout_apm/instruments/active_record.rb:421:in `save'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927625+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] devise (4.9.2) lib/devise/models/trackable.rb:40:in `update_tracked_fields!'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927626+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] devise (4.9.2) lib/devise/hooks/trackable.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927626+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/hooks.rb:15:in `block in _run_callbacks'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927626+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/hooks.rb:10:in `each'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927626+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/hooks.rb:10:in `_run_callbacks'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927627+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:52:in `_run_callbacks'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927627+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/proxy.rb:191:in `set_user'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927627+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/proxy.rb:339:in `_perform_authentication'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927627+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/proxy.rb:133:in `authenticate!'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927627+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] devise (4.9.2) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:19:in `create'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927628+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927628+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:228:in `process_action'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927628+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] scout_apm (2.6.10) lib/scout_apm/instruments/action_controller_rails_3_rails4.rb:100:in `process_action'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927628+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927628+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927628+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] activesupport (6.1.7.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:106:in `run_callbacks'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927629+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927634+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927634+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927634+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] activesupport (6.1.7.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927634+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] activesupport (6.1.7.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927635+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] activesupport (6.1.7.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927635+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `process_action'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927635+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:249:in `process_action'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927635+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] activerecord (6.1.7.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927635+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] scout_apm (2.6.10) lib/scout_apm/instruments/action_controller_rails_3_rails4.rb:117:in `process_action'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927635+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:165:in `process'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927635+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionview (6.1.7.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927635+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927635+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927638+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927638+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927639+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:19:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927639+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927639+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927639+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927639+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927639+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:842:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927639+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] scout_apm (2.6.10) lib/scout_apm/instruments/rails_router.rb:29:in `call_with_scout_instruments'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927639+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] rack-pjax (1.1.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927640+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] scout_apm (2.6.10) lib/scout_apm/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927640+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927640+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927640+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927640+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:697:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927640+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] remotipart (1.4.4) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:32:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927640+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927640+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927641+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927641+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927641+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927641+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927641+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927641+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] activesupport (6.1.7.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927641+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927641+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927642+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927642+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927642+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] railties (6.1.7.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927642+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] railties (6.1.7.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927642+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] activesupport (6.1.7.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927642+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] activesupport (6.1.7.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927642+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] activesupport (6.1.7.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927643+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] railties (6.1.7.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927643+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927643+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927643+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927645+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] activesupport (6.1.7.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927646+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927646+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927646+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927646+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:77:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927646+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] actionpack (6.1.7.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:142:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927646+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] rack-cors (1.1.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:100:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927646+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] scout_apm (2.6.10) lib/scout_apm/instruments/middleware_summary.rb:58:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927646+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] railties (6.1.7.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927647+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927647+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927647+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927647+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.927647+00:00 app[web.1]: [e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
2023-08-01T19:06:57.930990+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/sign_in" host=rbtest-backendv5-staging-0c772eac5283.herokuapp.com request_id=e8e8e771-1045-469a-8e4f-6343035c9fe0 fwd="49.206.41.146" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=133ms status=500 bytes=1891 protocol=https
```

Comment: Seriously lacking context here, but this is an error I have gotten a lot when upgrading installations. The cause could be the same: a hash of arguments instead of key-value pairs (use `key: value` instead of `{key: value}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of scout is very old and not passing through the `validate: false` as kwargs. Update Scout gem.

Comment: Hello Smathy, Thank you for editing the Question and text format.  We are not using Scout in our project  so, we removed it and deployed still getting same issue. 

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):

Comment: Put the new stacktrace up, it'll be some other old gem probably.

Comment: Hi Smathy, Solve the issue after remove Scout and delete Gem lock.  Thank you very much for your help.